# tty1 ~ tty6 frequently get frozen on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, tty, getty

It is wired that tty1 ~ tty6 frequently be fronzen on my Arch Linux. When this problem occurs, all the tty console（tty1 ~ tty6) display nothing but a underline cursor which is not blinking. However, I can even login into my system if I input the correct username and password. When I typing my username and password, there is nothing appear on the screen, but the login status can be checked via systemd's journal.

I really wondering why and how my tty can be stuck?

Comment: what is your kernel version?, did you recently upgrade your system?

Comment: My kernel is 4.4.39-1-lts #1 SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux, this is a fresh installed system, I just moved from Debian 8 to Arch.

Comment: Do you use grub or systemd boot?

Comment: I have both grub and systemd installed, I think grub is responsible for the system booting, I am not sure of it. How could I check this?

Comment: How does it freeze? Pressing ctrl-s blocks the terminal output. It can be fixed by pressing ctrl-q.

Comment: 4.4.39 is not an up-to-date LTS kernel from the Arch repositories. Please update your system and try again.

Comment: If you never ran `bootctl install [--path=esp directory]` then you did not install _systemd-boot_.  If you had run that you would have a _/boot/loader/_ subdirectory with a _loader.conf_ file in it.  Even if you had installed _systemd-boot_ , you would have had to manually create boot entries in _/boot/loader/entries/_.

Comment: @saga The tty screen seems not be refreshed at all. No matter what I typed, there is no response, however the command I typed in actually be executed, for example `reboot`.

Comment: @Wieland, I upgraded the whole system yesterday, problem seems gone. Time is needed to confirm.

Comment: @airhuff, What's the bonus if I switch booting method from grub to systemd?

Comment: @user3824053, I'm not saying there is an advantage or bonus.  A few posts up you said you weren't sure whether you were booting from grub or systemd-boot and I was just stating how to determine which.  I do not believe switching your boot loader would help you right now, and I doubt that's why saga asked about it.

Comment: @airhuff, sorry for that, I just a little bit curious about it. My system is booted by grub, I thinks this problem should be a bug (or my mis-config) of kernel or xorg.

Comment: @user3824053, no problem.  I suppose this could be a bug, it does seem odd.  Good luck!